# Checkbox in table to select table row in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a table in Angular 6, it has a checkbox in there? What I want to be able to do is select the table row, i.e checkbox, then hit a select button and that gets submitted. I was wondering does the table have to be wrapped in a `<form>`. The structure of my HTML so far is but it does not work:

```
 <form [formGroup]="assetForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <table class="table table-striped table-hover mb-10">
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Number</th>
              <th>Sev</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <tr *ngFor="let incident of data">
               <td>
                  <label class="form-radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="id_number" value="id_number">
                    <i class="form-icon"></i>{{incident.number}}
                  </label></td>
                <td>{{incident.sev}}</td>
                <td>{{incident.phone}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
       </table>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!Form.valid" type="submit">Select</button>
  </form>
```

**Ts.file**

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.assetForm.invalid) {
      this.assetForm.setErrors({ ...this.assetForm.errors, 'required': true });
      return;
    }
    this.uploading = true;
    this.service.post(this.assetForm.value).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);//On success response

    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log(errorResponse); //On unsuccessful response
      this.error = true;
      this.uploading = false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on what is not working, also can you reproduce the issue on https://stackblitz.com/ and share the link here

Comment: I have added some more code from the ts file and explained the issue more, hope that helps.

Comment: Is the post call entering `success` block or `error` block after form submission ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let incident of data">
    <td>
        <label class="form-radio">
           <input type="radio" name="id_number" value="id_number" [(ngModel)]="incident.checked">
           <i class="form-icon"></i>{{incident.number}}
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>{{incident.sev}}</td>
    <td>{{incident.phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

Try like, hope it will work.

Comment: Print the data value after click console.log(this.data). The data not part of form group